# Filter neo4j result, return distinct combination of node IDs

Tags: sql, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a graph with `Airport` nodes and `Flight` relationships, and I want to find triangles from a specific node where the edges are all within 10% length of each other.

```
MATCH path = (first:Airport{ID: 12953})-[f1:Flight]->
             (second:Airport)-[f2:Flight]->
             (third:Airport)-[f3:Flight]->
             (last:Airport{ID: 12953})
WHERE second.ID <>first.ID AND 
      third.ID <>first.ID AND 
      f1.Distance<=(1.1*f2.Distance) AND 
      f1.Distance<=(1.1*f3.Distance) AND 
      f2.Distance<=(1.1*f1.Distance) AND 
      f2.Distance<=(1.1*f3.Distance) AND 
      f3.Distance<=(1.1*f1.Distance) AND 
      f3.Distance<=(1.1*f2.Distance)
WITH (first.ID, second.ID, third.ID) as triplet
return count(DISTINCT triplet)
```

I only want to return a set of nodes once (no matter how many different flights exist between them), but the `with` line doesn't work. Basically what I want to create is a new type of variable "object" that has the three IDs as its properties and run distinct on that. Is that possible in neo4j? If not, is there some workaround?

Comment: Currently what I'm thinking about is since all IDs are 5 digit long, I multiply `first.ID` by 10^10, `second.ID` by 10^5 and add these together with unmodified `third.ID`, because that creates a unique number for each set of nodes. But that is a really ugly workaround in my opinion

Comment: Can you close the earlier version of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683952/min-max-value-of-a-paths-relationships-remove-duplicate-returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APOC function [apoc.coll.sort](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_collection_functions) to sort each list of 3 `ID`s, so that the `DISTINCT` option will properly treat lists with the same `ID`s as being the same.

Here is a simplified query that uses the APOC function:

```
MATCH path = (first:Airport{ID: 12953})-[f1:Flight]->
             (second:Airport)-[f2:Flight]->
             (third:Airport)-[f3:Flight]->
             (first)
WHERE second <> first <> third AND 
      f2.Distance<=(1.1*f1.Distance)>=f3.Distance AND
      f1.Distance<=(1.1*f2.Distance)>=f3.Distance AND 
      f1.Distance<=(1.1*f3.Distance)>=f2.Distance
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT apoc.coll.sort([first.ID, second.ID, third.ID]]))
```

*NOTE: the `second <> first` test may not be necessary since there should not be any flights (if a "flight" is the same as a "leg") that fly from an airport back to itself.*

Answer (score 1):

You can return an object with keys or an array. For example:

```
UNWIND range(1, 10000) AS i
WITH 
  { 
    id1: toInteger(rand()*3), 
    id2: toInteger(rand()*3), 
    id3: toInteger(rand()*3) 
  } AS triplet
RETURN DISTINCT triplet
```

or

```
UNWIND range(1, 10000) AS i
WITH 
  [ toInteger(rand()*3), toInteger(rand()*3), toInteger(rand()*3) ] AS triplet
RETURN DISTINCT triplet
```

**Update**. You can simplify your query by reusing a variable in the query, specifying the length of the path and using the list functions:

```
MATCH ps = (A:Airport {ID: 12953})-[:Flight*3]->(A)
WITH ps 
WHERE reduce(
  total = 0, 
  rel1 IN relationships(ps) | 
  total + reduce(
    acc = 0, 
    rel2 IN relationships(ps) | 
    acc + CASE WHEN rel1.Distance <= 1.1 * rel2.Distance THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  )) = 0
RETURN count(DISTINCT [n IN nodes(ps) | n.ID][0..3])
```